# Can the input variable of any polynomial function be a non-polynomial function?

Tags: functions, polynomials, hyperbolic-functions

Since the domain of a polynomial function is $\mathbb{R}$, can we replace the input variable $x$ of **any** polynomial function by a one-to-one *non-polynomial* function (with range $\mathbb{R}$) and get another polynomial function?

For example, if $p(x)$ is a polynomial function, then can we always define $x$ to be a function such as $ $ $\sinh u$, so that $p(\sinh u)$ is a polynomial function?

Or in other words, is the following conjecture true:

> For all polynomial functions $f(x)$ and for some function $g(x)$ with range and domain $R$, we can conclude that $f(g(x))$ is a polynomial function of $x$.

Comment: If $p(x)=x^2$ and $f(x)=|x|$ then $p(f(x))$ is again polynomial ...

Comment: It's a polynomial in $\sinh u$, but not a polynomial in $u$.

Comment: @Nick But doesn't the fact that $\sinh u$ is equal to a taylor series prevents this?

Comment: @Nick Post that comment as the answer. Simplest example is what it looks like when $p(x)=x$, since $\sinh$ isn't a polynomial.

Comment: Note that if $p(x)=x^6$ and $f(x)=\sqrt[3]x$, then $p(f(x))=x^2$ ...

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen So the answer to the OP's question is "sometimes". But that doesn't cover the particular example he asks about.

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen sorry, I poorly expressed what I meant, I just edited the post.

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen $x=u^{1/3}$, in the case of $p(x)=x^6$, is just one example, but can we find an example for **any** polynomial?

Comment: @Stephen No, because your polynomial could be $p(x) = x$. No matter what non-polynomial-function you input, it is not going to become a polynomial.

Comment: I just noticed the composition order in the conjecture is the opposite of the composition order in your example. The answer is still "no" in general, but you might want to edit the conjecture so that it agrees with the example and the description in the first paragraph of your question.

Comment: Done. I edited it a little to make it reflect more accurately what I meant. 
 Thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general, the answer is "no": the composition of a polynomial function and a non-polynomial function of some argument $u$  is *not* a polynomial function in $u$. As the comments make clear, there are exceptions.

In your example, all one can say is: It's a polynomial in $\sinh u$, but not a polynomial in $u$. E.g. if $p(x) = x$ and $f(u) = \sinh u$, then $p\circ f(u) = \sinh u$, certainly not a polynomial in u (unless you consider the Taylor series as a polynomial of infinite degree: that was a fruitful avenue for Euler, but lesser mortals should probably avoid it). If you think that "polynomial in $\sinh u$" is an unnatural concoction, the notion of a "polynomial in some transcendental function" does come in handy in certain contexts, e.g. $\cos nx = p(\cos x)$ for some polynomial $p$ (but $\cos nx$ is certainly not a polynomial in $x$).

[Thanks to Ethan Bolker for pushing this answer and suggesting the simple example.]